# Set cursor position inside a Datagrid cell and select text

Tags: wpf

Hi don't know how to put the cursor inside a DatagridCell and select all text

The code bellow set the focus on the cell, begin the edit. But the cursor is not inside the cell, so the user cannot begin to type text. Also the is not selected so user has to select manually the text instead of replacing value directly.

Mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
    private void GrdLignes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in GrdLignes.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (c.Column.Header.ToString() == "Quantité Livrée")
            {
                var cellContent = c.Column.GetCellContent(c.Item);
                if (cellContent != null)
                {
                    var dc = (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
                    dc.Focus();
                    dc.IsEditing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

EDIT: I say cursor = blinking caret

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait until the `TextBlock` in the cell has been replaced by a `TextBox`.

Define an `EditingElementStyle` and handle the `Loaded` event for the `TextBox`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GridLignes" ...>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="tbStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="OnLoaded" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantité Livrée" Binding="{Binding Qty}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource tbStyle}" />
        ...
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    Keyboard.Focus(textBox);
    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
    textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: It worked well. I've been searching for a while thanks a lot